# How to replace the image of the back button entirely with different image?

Tags: iphone

Below is my coding

```
// Navigation logic may go here -- for example, create and push another view controller.
NextViewController *nextViewController = 
[[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
[nextViewController release];

UIImage *backImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbutton.png"]; 
UIBarButtonItem * backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                       initWithImage:backImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil 
                                       action:nil]; 
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem; 
[backBarButtonItem release];

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here, from my own project. (I am doing this in viewDidLoad)

```
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"btn-custom-back.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(popView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; 

    UIView *buttonView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, image.size.width, image.size.height)];
    [buttonView addSubview:button];

    UIBarButtonItem *backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:buttonView];
    [buttonView release];

    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem;
    [backItem release];
```

And the method:

```
- (void)popView {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have used your codes and the back button is replaced entirely, but it doesn't function properly. This means when I click on it, the application becomes frozen.

Comment: @David: Could you post the code where you are trying to do so?

Comment: I'm trying to do it in the subclass under the comment                                                             // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.                                               - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 self.title = @"Search";
}

Comment: @David: Ok, that is correct. You are of course using a UINavigationController and you have added the -(void)popView in the header-file?

Answer (score 1):

The modification to the back button has to be done before you push the new view controller onto the navigation stack.

So just move your code around to look like this:

```
UIImage *backImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"backbutton.png"]; 
UIBarButtonItem * backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                   initWithImage:backImage style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil 
                                   action:nil]; 
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backBarButtonItem; 
[backBarButtonItem release];

NextViewController *nextViewController = 
[[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:nextViewController animated:YES];
[nextViewController release];
```